# Play video file from certain timestamps in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to customize the playback of videos I have added to MatLab by setting them to play from a specific start point, rather than playing from the beginning.

By using MathWorks' VideoReader, I can determine the target start frames, duration, frame rate, etc.

How can I tell MatLab to play my video starting at, say, the 3 sec, or 5 sec mark? Or any other mark I choose?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  What do you mean by "play starting at the 3 second mark"?  Do you want to have blank frames for 3 seconds, then start playing the video after that?

Comment: I want  to hit play  and have it start playing from t=3sec like if i put t=1m14s  at the end of my youtube link it starts 1m14seconds into  the video.

Comment: OK.  I don't seem to be understanding what you're trying to do.  Is there code you wrote to help us understand what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do one thing by using the VideoReader you will get whole video which contain frames and audio. now you split by like this LET ASSUME 10 seconds video CONTAINS 200 FRAMES and starting time is 2 sec and ending time is 4 second.
so 2 sec video = 40 frame and 4 sec video = 80 . now put one loop for frame 40 to 80 then store it in temp variable. afer then play that frames by using movie. I think below code will use for  you.

```
sampling_factor = 8;
resizing_params = [100 120];

%%// Input video
xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');

%%// Setup other parameters
nFrames = floor(xyloObj.NumberOfFrame/sampling_factor); %%// xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = resizing_params(1); %// xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = resizing_params(1); %// xyloObj.Width;
% here i am play 4 sec movie to 2 to 3
info = get(xyloObj);
duration =info.Duration;
startframe =round( nFrames *2/duration); % 2 means starting duration in sec  
endframe = round( nFrames *4/duration); % 4 means ending duration in sec  
%// Preallocate movie structure.
temp(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),'colormap',[]);
mov = temp(1:endframe-startframe) ;
indx =1;
%// Read one frame at a time.
for k = 1 :nFrames
    if k >=startframe && k <=endframe  
        IMG = read(xyloObj, (k-1)*sampling_factor+1);
    %// IMG = some_operation(IMG);
         mov(indx).cdata = imresize(IMG,[vidHeight vidWidth]);
         indx =indx +1;
    end    
end

%// Size a figure based on the video's width and height.
hf = figure;
set(hf, 'position', [150 150 vidWidth vidHeight])

%// Play back the movie once at the video's frame rate.
movie(hf, mov, 1, xyloObj.FrameRate);
```

Comment: what is the sampling factor?

Comment: by changing the sampling factor and run the code . you will understand  about the sampling factor.

Comment: Why don't you give a one sentence answer that describes what the sampling factor is?... Unless you don't know that yourself? I don't want to have to find a video file, copy and paste this code in, and run it to figure it out. If you put a small sentence on what it does, it'll help your post.

Comment: sampling factor is the number of samples of data recorded in a given period of time. let assume total number of frame is 160 for 4 second. then sampling factor is 8 then now total number of factor is 160 / 8 = 20 . During capture the frame, **read(xyloObj, (k-1)*sampling_factor+1)** in this **(k-1)*sampling_factor+1**  formula for calculate frame index.   I think this explain is enough. If you need more tell me i will give more explanation

Comment: @KathickRajan So it defines the playback frame rate?  Alternatively if I have a video recorded at 30fps, and data collected at 10Hz, can I set the sampling factor to 10 and that would sync a graph of data (which I have animated to draw) with the video output?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running 14b or higher, VideoReader has a property called CurrentTime that you can set.

So you can say

```
vidObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');
vidObj.CurrentTime = 2; % 2 seconds;
readFrame(vidObj);
```

Hope this helps.